# Result involving bundles

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to know if I can have an inequivalent but weakly equivalent bundles over the Torus, i.e. if we can find explicitly an example of a bundle map $(\overline{f},f)$ where we require that $\overline{f}$ is an isomorphism from one fibre to another and $f$ an homeomorphism from the torus to the torus but such that $f$ is not the identity map (if this happens we will have an equivalence).

---

> **Notes**

- This restlessness is taken from Spivak's A comprehensive introduction to differential geometry,third edition,chapter 3.
- I'm a beginner here so I don't know anything about cohomology, fancy differential geometry or that stuff thanks for your support.

**Definition**

---

> A weak equivalence between two bundles over the same base space $B$ is
>   a bundle map $(\overline{f},f)$ where $\overline{f}$ is an isomorphism
>   on each fibre, and $f$ is a homeomorphism of $B$ into itself.

Comment: Sorry, what does it mean for bundles over the torus to be inequivalent but weakly equivalent?

Comment: This is different :)

Comment: I could delete the other one right?

Comment: OK, so weakly equivalent means that the isomorphism needn't cover the identity. I don't see how your question differs from the previous.

Comment: Ok let me then delete the other one and edit this one right :) and yes that is the definition

Comment: Well I didn't delete it but I voted to close it :) then what can be done?

Comment: You cannot delete it, it has an upvoted answer. That answer might be helpful to someone else. It is completely unclear to me how this question is different; nobody can answer to your satisfaction if they don't know what the problem was with the previous answer.

Comment: The problem with the previous answer was as I posted that I don't know anything about cohomology and fancy stuff is posted in Notes :)

Comment: Is the same question but no one was paying attention to the previous question and I decide to make clearer what I was expecting

Comment: @user162343, **please** do not ask new copies of a version «to attract attention». I will close this one. I suggest you edit the old one to make it clear what you seem to think needs to be made clear. That will bump the question in the main page.

Comment: Sorry :) Then I should edit my question a as may times as I require even if then nobody is watching? Or what should I do?

Comment: Ok I have edited my previous question :)